# asp.net core - Integration test and view components

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I'm facing a strange issue since I created a view component in my app.
All my integration tests using an HttpClient start failing with response code "Internal Server Error".

Here the test configuration :

```
public class BaseTest<TStartup>
        : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
    {
        private readonly bool _hasUser;
        private readonly HttpClient _client;

        protected BaseTest(bool hasUser = false)
        {
            _hasUser = hasUser;
            _client = CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = false,
            });
        }

        protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetPageByPath(string path)
        {
            return await _client.GetAsync(path);
        }

        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                if (_hasUser)
                {
                    services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationServiceStub>();
                    services.AddSingleton<IStartupFilter, FakeUserFilter>();
                    services.AddMvc(options =>
                    {
                        options.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());
                        options.Filters.Add(new AuthenticatedAttribute());
                    });
                }
            });

            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                // Create a new service provider.
                ServiceProvider serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                    .BuildServiceProvider();

                // Build the service provider.
                var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                // Create a scope to obtain a reference to the database
                // context (ApplicationDbContext).
                using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
                {
                    var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                    var logger = scopedServices
                        .GetRequiredService<ILogger<BaseTest<TStartup>>>();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And a usage example :

```
public class BasicTest : BaseTest<Startup>
    {
        public BasicTest() : base()
        {
        }

        [Theory]
        [InlineData("/")]
        [InlineData("/Index")]
        [InlineData("/Users/SignOut")]
        [Trait("Category", "Integration")]
        public async Task Get_EndpointsReturnSuccessAndCorrectContentType(string url)
        {
            // Act
            var response = await GetPageByPath(url);

            // Assert
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Status Code 200-299
            Assert.Equal("text/html; charset=utf-8",
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
        }
    }
```

If you need the component code let me know.

I already rollback code to check when this start happening, and it's start after the commit with the new Component called in several pages.

Comment: What goes inside of the component code? If you  can see the 500 HTTP error then you probably should be able to see the call stack or to debug your application during integration test run.

Comment: it's only a basic breadcrumb with a dictionary as parameters. I did not think to debug, I was very disappointed about this strange issue :/